# WPF shows same lines differently

Tags: wpf, graphics

I draw X straight lines. Same thickness, etc. but every fourth line looks visibly different - it's thinner.

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas">
    <Line X1="100" Y1="100" X2="500" Y2="100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="125" X2="500" Y2="125" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="150" X2="500" Y2="150" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="175" X2="500" Y2="175" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="200" X2="500" Y2="200" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="225" X2="500" Y2="225" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="250" X2="500" Y2="250" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="275" X2="500" Y2="275" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>
    <Line X1="100" Y1="300" X2="500" Y2="300" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"/>

</Canvas>
```

It doesn't matter whether render option is alias or unspecified. Both outputs display lines that aren't identical.
I even set Windows DPI to be 100% and it still looks the same.

How it could be fixed ? Anyone experienced this ?

Comment: I have tried your code and can not reproduce your scenario. Have you tried to run the code in another machine?

Comment: Nope but @megadan's answer solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling `SnapsToDevicePixels` on your `Canvas`.

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

This will reduce anti-aliasing artifacts and ensure the lines are drawn on pixel boundaries.